# how to get selected text from dropdown binded trhough jquery in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to get selected Text from dropdown in which data is binded through jQuery and use in c# function for display.

[image: This is the image of front end]**Page design and jquery calling function**

```
<script src="../../JavaScript/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=ddlCountry]").change(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "testing.aspx/getstateList",
                data: '{value: "' + $(this).val() + '"}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (r) {
                    var ddlCustomers = $("[id*=ddlState]");
                    ddlCustomers.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="">Select an State</option>');
                    $.each(r.d, function () {
                        ddlCustomers.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                    });
                }
            })
        })
    });
</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">

            <label for="validate-select">Country Name:</label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" >
                    <asp:ListItem Value="">Select an Country</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>

            <label for="validate-select">State Name:</label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlState" runat="server">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="">Select an State</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>



        <asp:Button ID="btnsave" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnsave_Click"  />
```

**getting data from database table using webmethod**

```
 [WebMethod]
public static List<ListItem> getstateList(string value)
{
    SqlConnection strConnection = new SqlConnection("connection string"); 
    strConnection.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select state_name as 'output', id from stateMaster where country_id='101' and Status='ACTIVE' order by state_name", strConnection);   

    List<ListItem> customers = new List<ListItem>();

    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();//opr.getDataReaderTrans("select state_name as 'output', id from stateMaster where country_id='101' and Status='ACTIVE' order by state_name");

    while (sdr.Read())
    {
        customers.Add(new ListItem
        {
            Value = sdr["id"].ToString(),
            Text = sdr["output"].ToString()
        });
    }
    return customers;
}
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string state = ddlState.SelectedItem.Text;

    Response.Write(state);
}
```

Comment: what is your problem and where you getting it? please explain properly. Form your question it is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dropdownlist.SelectedItem.Text` to get the selected item's text and `dropdownlist.SelectedValue` to get the selected items value in code behind.

Check below sample :

```
protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Retrieve Selected Text from Dropdown
    var countrySelText = ddlCountry.SelectedItem.Text;
    //Retrieve Selected Value from Dropdown
    var countrySelValue = ddlCountry.SelectedValue;

    //Retrieve Selected Text from Dropdown
    var stateSelText = ddlState.SelectedItem.Text;
    //Retrieve Selected Value from Dropdown
    var stateSelValue = ddlState.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: this returns nothing

Comment: Nothing means? Do you have any selected item? try putting a breakpoint and check

Answer (score 0):

for getting selected text you can use:

```
var _Selected = document.getElementById("yourdropdownID");
var _SelectedIndex = _Selected.options[_Selected.selectedIndex].text;
```

or if you want to get the value:

```
var _Selected = document.getElementById("yourdropdownID");
var _SelectedIndex = _Selected.options[_Selected.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: I want this value in C# function on button click